# ! Undefined control sequence. \@urlcolor with custom documentclass

Tags: errors, hyperref, document-classes

I am trying to debug a custom `documentclass` that I need to use, in which the `hyperref` package (`\href` command) doesn't work.

This is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \href{http://link}{text}
  
\end{document}
```

Compiles fine. When I change the `documentclass` to `nohref` with `nohref.cls` being

```
\def\document{
  \everypar{}
}
```

it fails to compile, throwing

```
\hyper@linkurl ...tionraw >>}\relax \Hy@colorlink 
                                                  \@urlcolor #1\Hy@xspace@en...
l.9   \href{http://link}{text}
```

How do I need to change my code to make this work?

Comment: the nohref.cls you show redefines `\document` and will completely break latex, it's suprising that anything works without error. what is the intention of that file?

Comment: Well... It's a template for official letters from our university with headers, logo etc. that seems to have been passed on from generation to generation. According to the comments it's almost 30 years old ^^

Comment: Note: It's actually a 840-lines class definition, I just removed all of it line by line to come up with the minimal example here.

Comment: but if it contains that definition of  `\document` then it can never possibly have worked.

Comment: It is possible that you deleted too much, 840 lines isn't that much you could post the whole thing, in particular if the `zzz` example in my example works without error with the real class  then you have deleted too much.

Comment: OK. In its original form it does work (until you try to use, e.g., the hyperref package...) I certainly have removed too much (e.g. `\normalsize` is redefined etc.), because my intention was just to reproduce the error I see.

Comment: Let me upload it somewhere and post the link.

Comment: I meant just add it here, but OK

Comment: minimal examples are good but in this case it was impossible to think of anything that would produce an error free document even if you removed the link color error.

Comment: Can also add it here :) Buuut I'll need to go through the file and remove some of the hardcoded defaults that might violate data protection :/

Comment: a link is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129728/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-fuenfundachtzig).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class file shown completely breaks LaTeX, essentially nothing will work.

Redefining `\document` means that  none of the things that normally are set up at `\begin{document}` happen.

```
\documentclass{nohref}

\begin{document}

zzz
  
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--6
```

as the text width is not set up

```
! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.
```

as `\normalsize` is not defined

```
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

as the aux file has not been opened for writing.

```
! I can't find file `file.aux'.
\enddocument ...keatletter \@@input \jobname .aux
```

Because the aux file was not written so can not be input at the end.

Specifically with `hyperref` none of the setup that it normally does `\AtBeginDocument` happens as the redefined `\document` never runs that code.
But the exact error is fairly arbitrary as essentially no LaTeX constructs will work and will generate errors at more or less arbitrary internal failures.

---

In the linked chat the OP confirmed that the actual class being used was not *quite* as minimal, but almost as bad, it defined `\document` based on the LaTeX2.09 definition so in particular it does *not* run any code specified to run in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` any code specified to run there is silently discarded.

`hyperref` like many other classes delays lots of its setup with `\AtBeginDocument` which is why the colour in particular failed.

Adding the two lines below to run the AtBeginDocumentHook is a minimal patch to make the example work, but the class has not really been usable for 30 years.  Note `\document` has further changes to add more hooks in the 2021 release and these are all broken by this class, you would need
`\RequirePackage[2020/01/01]{latexrelease}` in the document to undo these updates.

---

**UPDATED AFTER COMMENTS**

```
\def\document{\endgroup
 \@colht\textheight \@colroom\textheight \vsize\textheight
 \columnwidth\textwidth \@clubpenalty\clubpenalty
 \if@twocolumn \advance\columnwidth -\columnsep
 \divide\columnwidth\tw@ \hsize\columnwidth \@firstcolumntrue
 \fi
 \hsize\columnwidth \linewidth\hsize
 \begingroup\@floatplacement\@dblfloatplacement\endgroup
 \if@filesw \immediate\openout\@mainaux=\jobname.aux
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\startlabels\string\@startlabels}\fi
% support \AtBeginDocment
  \let\AtBeginDocument\@firstofone
  \@begindocumenthook
%
 \def\do##1{\let ##1\@notprerr}
 \@preamblecmds
 \let\do\noexpand
 \@normalsize\everypar{}%
}
```